# Does gravity affect dark matter?

Tags: gravity, dark-matter, galaxies

On this photo the red color is ionized gas and a blue color is a fark matter. We see the shockwave on gas but the clouds of dark matter move through each other without any interactions. The dark matter doesn't affect by electromagnetic interactions so it can penetrate through each other without slowing down but what is about the gravity? If it produces gravity, it has mass, so, it should be affected by gravity. But there is no a shock wave in the dark matter clouds.

So, does the gravity produced by dark matter affect the other dark matter? Why two clouds don't interact with each other? Does the dark matter ignores the curvature of spacetime?

[image: The Bullet galaxy]

Comment: There is no link for the paper that shows the photo. also I see no waves in the red either

Comment: @annav the red area is the luminous matter, and the blue is an artificially shaded dark matter blob measured from lensing, this is the famous bullet cluster a so called smoking gun example of dark matter.

Comment: @Triatticus yes, foundit in wiki, but I see no shock waves  that the question asks

Comment: Red gas on right. Look on it's shape

Comment: Indeed we will need someone more versed in cosmology to answer this, @Robotex however it's already assumed that dark matter self gravitates, that's just a result of it having mass-energy, it wouldn't make sense to posit matter that doesn't gravitate and yet gravitates with normal matter, but you're talking about interactions between extremely diffuse blobs and the weakest of the forces. Here the luminous matter is undergoing a much stronger interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Everything* gravitates.

In fact the blue "dark matter" clouds in the image were created by mapping the gravitational lensing of background stars by the dark matter cloud.

The blue clouds passed through the collision because of their inertia. However they do exert a gravitational force on each other, which will decelerate the clouds. Keep in mind you are only looking at a snapshot, of a process that will take a very long time to complete.

You wouldn't expect gravity to create a shockwave in this situation. The shock in the baryonic matter ultimately comes from electromagnetic interactions.

Comment: So, the red clouds moves much slower because they collided with each other and blue clouds not, am I right? And gravitational deceleration was the same for both colors of clouds?

Comment: @Robotex Basically yes.

Comment: Presumably the gravitational decelearation for the red clouds is somewhat larger because the  two red clouds are closer to the center of gravity, and gravity becomes weaker over distance.

Comment: Yes, but there was a moment when distance between clouds of the dark matter was the same as between barionic matter

Comment: @Robotex Fair enough, at that moment the deceleration would be the same. I was referring to the moment in the image.

Comment: Answer is accepted

Answer (score 0):

Dark matter is the spacetime fabric

[Dark Matter More Ubiquitous Than We Ever Thought](https://www.inverse.com/article/24863-dark-matter-might-be-smoother-than-we-thought)

> dark matter is smooth, distributed more evenly throughout space than we thought

[Dark matter is on the move: Scientists find the elusive material can be pushed out of a galaxy's center by star formation](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-6554999/Dark-matter-Scientists-material-pushed-galaxys-center.html)

> ‘The dark matter at the centres of star-forming dwarfs appears to have been “heated up” and pushed out.’

Dark matter is smoothly distributed and pushed out by stars.

What is referred to geometrically as curved spacetime physically exists as displaced dark matter.

Displaced dark matter is the physical manifestation of gravity.

A galaxy's halo is not a clump of dark matter traveling with the galaxy. A galaxy's halo is displaced dark matter.

The 'missing mass' associated with dark matter is the mass of the dark matter connected to and neighboring a galaxy which is displaced by the galaxy.

The dark matter displaced by a galaxy 'displaces back', causing the stars in the outer arms of the galaxy to orbit the galactic center at the rate in which they do. The dark matter displaced by the quarks the Earth consists of, pushing back and exerting pressure toward the Earth, causes gravity.

[Scientists Thought All Galaxies Had Dark Matter, but They Just Found One Without It](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/galaxy-without-dark-matter-shakes-astronomy-180968628/)

> Analysis shows the ultra-diffuse DF2 lies about 6.5 million light years away and is roughly the same size as our own Milky Way galaxy, but contains 200 times fewer stars.

The reason for the mistaken notion that the galaxy is missing dark matter is that the galaxy is so diffuse that it doesn't displace the dark matter outward and away from it to the degree that the dark matter is able to push back and cause the stars far away from the galactic center to speed up. The galaxy is too diffuse to displace the dark matter to such an extent that it causes the light to lense as it passes by the galaxy.

[The Milky Way's dark matter halo appears to be lopsided](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3802)

> the dark matter halo of the Milky Way is dominantly lopsided in nature.

The Milky Way's halo is lopsided due to the ordinary matter in the Milky Way moving through and displacing the dark matter, analogous to a submarine moving through and displacing the water.

[Offset between dark matter and ordinary matter](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1475)

> the gravitational potential in clusters is mainly due to a non-baryonic fluid

The center of the light lensing through the space neighboring the galaxy clusters and the center of the galaxy clusters themselves is offset due to the galaxy clusters moving through and displacing the dark matter, analogous to submarines moving through and displacing the water.

In the [Bullet Cluster](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Cluster) collision the dark matter has not separated from the ordinary matter. The collision is analogous to two boats that collide, the boats slow down and their bow waves continue to propagate. The water has not separated from the boats, the bow waves have. In the Bullet Cluster collision the galaxy's associated displacement waves in the dark matter have separated from the colliding galaxies, causing the light to lense as it passes through the waves.

[Hubble Finds Ghostly Ring of Dark Matter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Cluster)

> Astronomers using NASA’s Hubble Space Telescope got a first-hand view of how dark matter behaves during a titanic collision between two galaxy clusters. The wreck created a ripple of dark matter, which is somewhat similar to a ripple formed in a pond when a rock hits the water. ... when the two clusters smash together, the dark matter falls to the center of the combined cluster and sloshes back out.

When two boats collide their bow waves fall to the center of the boats and the water sloshes back out.

Particles of ordinary matter move through and displace the dark matter, causing it to wave. Wave-particle duality is a moving particle and its associated wave in the dark matter.